# How laravel relationship Has One response null to convert in blank object?

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 table and 1 table i have record and another table i have not record in that case i want blank object not null in laravel hasOne relationship.

I have check and found withDefault() of laravel but that not return blank object that return with single key.

OutPut:

```
{
"id": 3,
"name": "S",
"test": {
    "test_1_id": 3
   }
}
```

Expected-OutPut:

```
{
"id": 3,
"name": "S",
"test": {}
}
```

```
public function test(){
    return $this->hasOne('\App\TestTwo',"test_1_id","id")->withDefault();
}
```

Can any one help me on this.

Note::

1. I have multiple records in the first table and i am fetching all record.
2. I am fetching record from first table and some of row related record is not available in the second table.
3. I want when second table not available data in that case i want response in blank object of array as per expected output.

Comment: But in your example that are clearly rows in both tables? That makes, the question hard to understand what you actually want. Also defaulting empty relationships to empty object instead of null, i have never seen that, and i have been on a couple of bigger API projects.

Comment: @mrhn i just want hasOne relationship response to null to object array(If data not available in second table)

Comment: But in your example that are clearly rows in both tables?
 ==> @mrhn No, Record only in First Table which is my main table.

In the second table which table i want to fetch records using has-one that table i have not any row related this records